# Not able to render table of results properly in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

Options.js

```
    return (
      <div>
        <Table bordered hover variant="light">
          <caption>Data Inspector Results</caption>
          <thead className="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th>Attribute</th>
              <th>Datatype</th>
              <th>Categorical/Numerical</th>
              <th>Sample Data</th>
              <th>Null Values</th>
              <th>Numerical Range</th>
              <th>Bin Size</th>
              <th>Unique Key</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {result}
            {result}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    )
```

Result.js

```
return (
    <div>
        <tr>
          <td>{props.attribute}</td>
          <td>{props.dataType}</td>
          <td>
            <Select options={categoryOptions} />
          </td>
          <td>To Be Done In The Future</td>
          <td>
            <Select
              defaultValue={[]}
              isMulti
              name="colors"
              options={nullBinOptions}
              className="basic-multi-select"
              classNamePrefix="select"
            />
          </td>
          <td>{props.numericalRange}</td>
          <td>{props.binSize}</td>
          <td>NA</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
)
```

I'm trying to render multiple of my result component within `Options.js`. However, I'm facing this issue where my results are not displaying properly in the table.

This image shows my issues

[image]

The `props` aren't the issue nor the `JSON` that I'm feeding in. I can't seem to render this table nicely. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: @Gawel1908 Doesn't work. It still reflects the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping result inside a `div` you should un-wrap it and leave as a `tr`.

```js
return (
        <tr>
          <td>{props.attribute}</td>
          <td>{props.dataType}</td>
          <td>
            <Select options={categoryOptions} />
          </td>
          <td>To Be Done In The Future</td>
          <td>
            <Select
              defaultValue={[]}
              isMulti
              name="colors"
              options={nullBinOptions}
              className="basic-multi-select"
              classNamePrefix="select"
            />
          </td>
          <td>{props.numericalRange}</td>
          <td>{props.binSize}</td>
          <td>NA</td>
        </tr>
)
```

Using chrome-dev-tools are you able to share an image of the html tree?

About `TABLE` elements: It's very important that the immediate structure are the expected elements (`TBODY`, `THEAD`, `TR`, `TD`, `TH`) as tables are very rigid structures and putting elements such as `DIV` where the DOM expects a `TD` for example put's it in "quirk" mode and layout will probable misbehave. https://css-tricks.com/using-divs-inside-tables/

Comment: Hi @Edorka I've tried doing so. It still reflects the same issue!

Comment: Hi @Edorka! I've uploaded the link in my question. Does that help?

Comment: yes, and the wrapping <div> on the Result component is the one causing that issue

Comment: Wow. It works now. Could you explain why the wrapping <div> has caused this error?

Comment: Sure give me a moment

Answer (score 0):

Can you just update your files like this and check again

Options.js

```
return (
    <Table bordered hover variant="light">
      <caption>Data Inspector Results</caption>
      <thead className="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>Attribute</th>
          <th>Datatype</th>
          <th>Categorical/Numerical</th>
          <th>Sample Data</th>
          <th>Null Values</th>
          <th>Numerical Range</th>
          <th>Bin Size</th>
          <th>Unique Key</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
        {result}
        {result}
    </Table>
)
```

Result.js

```
return (
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{props.attribute}</td>
      <td>{props.dataType}</td>
      <td>
        <Select options={categoryOptions} />
      </td>
      <td>To Be Done In The Future</td>
      <td>
        <Select
          defaultValue={[]}
          isMulti
          name="colors"
          options={nullBinOptions}
          className="basic-multi-select"
          classNamePrefix="select"
        />
      </td>
      <td>{props.numericalRange}</td>
      <td>{props.binSize}</td>
      <td>NA</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>)
```

Comment: I've followed your edits accordingly. Im still facing the same error!